# Is it possible to open a spotfire analysis file stored in memory?

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to figure out if there is a way how I can pass a dxp analysis file from memory to the API (i.e. the file is not stored in the library). So the call would be something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
      window.onload = function() {
            var customization = new spotfire.webPlayer.Customization();
            customization.showClose = false;

            // can I pass dxp file in memory like that?
            var file = new AnalysisFile();
            var app = new spotfire.webPlayer.Application(htmlRawModelAnalyticsserver,
                customization,
                file);

            var doc = app.openDocument("spotfire-container", htmlRawModelLaunchpage);
        }
</script>
```

I am using Spotfire version 10.1

Comment: is this related to your other question? what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @niko Thank you for your comment. My goal is to be able to pass a regular object (representing an analytsis file) to Spotfire to open instead of specifying a path to that file in the library. For example, my analysis file can be stored somewhere else. Is it possible to pass an object (if spotfire api support that) instead of a path?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't very specific. what I mean is, what is your use case for circumventing the Spotfire Library? where are you getting your "regular object representing an analysis file"? I ask because it sounds like you're trying to create a mashup but it's not really clear.

Comment: @niko I understand, well right now my team and I are investigating what are the limitations of the library so that we know what to expect and what to say to our customer when their request a feature X. We are not sure how flexible the library is. That is the main reason behind really. Ideally, it would be great if we can serialize an analysis file and store it on a server (not spotfire), deserialize it and pass it to spotfire as shown above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your last comment I'm going to suggest that you look into the [JavaScript API](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfire-javascript-api-overview). from the documentation there:

> With the TIBCO Spotfire® JavaScript API it is possible to embed
>   Spotfire visualizations and dashboards into web pages. The API
>   supports customized layout and enables integration with external web
>   applications.
>
> The JavaScript API can be used for a diverse set of scenarios:
>
> - Embed Spotfire visualizations into a corporate web site.
> - Open an Spotfire analysis from a link, and configure the data or the analysis depending on the user.
> - Integrate Spotfire analyses with other web applications.
>
> The JavaScript API supports opening multiple views
>   against the same analysis, where all views are automatically linked
>   together. This gives a lot of flexibility when creating a mashup.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That does sound like it would put us in a better position. However, I am not sure if the JavaScript API will allow passing an analysis file other than a path to an existing one in the library from what I have seen on the JS API docs. I may have missed it but I don't think I have come across anything like that.

Comment: that is a correct assumption. I don't immediately know how you would get the analysis "into memory" though. if you can expand on that I may be able to provide a better, or at least more specific, answer.

Comment: Not a problem. I am not able to expand on that, unfortunately as we are (at that point) investigating what is possible or not. I suppose if the file MUST be read from the library there can be some other ways how we can create a file and store it in the Spotfire library using the LibraryService (or some other service) and then supply this path to the JavaScript API.

Comment: I guess the question I'm struggling with is "why would you ever want to remove a core part of the product and reimplement it on your own?" if you can better define the problem, I may be able to provide a clearer answer, but most likely it will involve using the library.

Comment: are you trying to automate the creation of an analysis?

Comment: I understand. I am sorry I can't be more specific. We are doing initial research on the capabilities of the library. No, we are not (at that point of time) trying to automate that but I suppose that we can utilize the Automation Services? I will accept your answer as you have provided a lot of feedback and suggestions :)